# Can I retrieve my Flex .swf and images from different Amazon S3 buckets?

Tags: image, flex3, flash, amazon-s3, crossdomain.xml

I have a Flex 3 SWF in one Amazon S3 bucket, which dynamically loads images for buttons which are stored in another S3 bucket.

I have set a completely open crossdomain.xml file in each bucket, but when I call the SWF from my web site, only a few button images load - and they're just the 'up' or 'normal' state button images (i.e. not 'down', 'over' or 'disabled').

I had hoped that just setting an open crossdomain.xml policy file would have been enough to allow me to pull images across these different domains, but it's clearly not working.

I'd like as simple-a-solution as possible, but I have been reading about using either a SHIM movie (which doesn't sound straightforward) or using PHP, for example, as a proxy - but I don't think I can do this with S3, as it's not an actual server, as such.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts on this from people who have done something similar.

Comment: Have you tried loading the images from another web site, just to verify it is an amazon s3 specific problem?

Comment: Hi James.  Thanks for commenting so quickly.  I haven't tried this yet - I'll give it a go and report back here.  It may well not be specific to S3, in which case I'll still need a solution to generally loading images/data from different domains.

From reading around this a bit more, perhaps the ActionScript Security.LoadPolicyFile() is going to sort this for me.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to follow-up on this, I did as James Lawruk suggested and brought the content to a local server, where it was still failing.  Some things I hadn't appreciated before I started looking at this, and what I learned:

- Amazon S3 buckets support nested structures (for some reason I'd convinced myself they could only hold flat file structures - I don't know why!)
- placing a `crossdomain.xml` file in the root of the S3 bucket was the key to sorting this out
- `crossdomain.xml` files changed in Flash Player 9 onwards and - I believe - in v10 onwards there are extra commands to do with master file behaviour, which I needed to implement.

Some links of interest:

http://www.jodieorourke.com/view.php?id=108&blog=news

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2011